# dapper.net cache to keep data in memory

Tags: c#, dapper

I have a web application (Logi Analytic's Logi info) that is hosted in IIS. This application has to invoke a method in a tailor made dll called plugin (written in C# as a class library).

The method will perform some data access to invoke some sproc in a legacy SQL server database. I will probably use Dapper.Net. I am just wondering what I can do to improve performance - to ensure that the data is kept in memory - to avoid round trips to the database?

Comment: You do or don't have access to change the website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dapper has no function for caching objects in memory this way.
The problem with caching sql result is how to handle removed and edited items.

Take a look at this @ [Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43434/A-Simple-Way-to-Cache-Objects-and-Collections-for)